# How to use Math operations in ejs? ie. Math.ceil()

Tags: javascript, ejs

I am required to do some mathematic operations in my ejs file. I tried using Math.ceil() but I am receiving an error. Is it possible to use the Math library in ejs and how?

Comment: Why you are doing it on the `view` just handle all the stuff in the JavaScript file and pass the value to the `template`

Comment: @RoguSmith why didn't I think of that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem during one project.

[Here the buy/sell values had decimals and I wanted to remove the decimals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6XTP.jpg)

So I implemented this code inside my ejs file and the decimals were removed

[This is the code that I implemented inside my ejs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtvUs.jpg).

[My problem got resolved using this approach, you can also apply the same approach.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2in8.jpg)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)